# Entity.list() Hibernate Performance

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application that I inherited with an admittedly poor data model. For the time being, I'm trying to put a bandaid on it.

We've noticed increasingly poor performance as more data is loaded into the system, even on operations that should be working with a queried subset of the data (i.e. one record at a time).

We're using New Relic and I've noticed that a significant portion of our request time is spent in `EntityName.list()` on transactions that utilize Criteria Queries. None of our entities even have a `list()` method, though. It's my understanding that Criteria Queries are translated to SQL and the query actually happens on the database engine, rather than listing all entities and then querying the Java objects. Is that accurate? Any idea what the `list()` method in New Relic is?

Just to be clear, I realize that doing a list all or `select * ...` on a huge table would take a while. The issue is that we're using Criteria Queries to query the table, not list all records. My question is: where does the reference to `Entity.list()` in New Relic come from?

Comment: Whatever that `list` method is, I guess it's selecting all rows with a query such as `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`. If your table is huge, that might take some time...

Comment: I think use VisualVM or Jprofiler and coverage  your code where you think bad and find line to creator this issue

Answer (score 0):

- Infact, we should not use the list() method generally, a simple
  improvement is puting a "select field1, field2,... from ...." and try
  to remove any large field in the list (unless it really necessary)
- Another impact from the list is because of relation ship. If you have
  one or multiple relationship between Entities, hibernate will load
  the related entities if the relation ship marked EAGER, even with
  LAZY, it still requires some extra information.
- If you really want to get list, try to create a view base on the data
  and make entities which matched with that view, it may improve
  performance a bit.

Comment: I'm not using list. There is no list method. I'm using criteria queries which, as far as I can tell *should not* be doing a `select * ...`